# Unity how to update shooting&bullet to custom server?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, networking, server

I created my own server instead of using the networking Unity provide. But I have a problem with sending the bullet information to the server so the other players on the network can see the bullets when someone shoots. Here is the code I have:

```
string ImPlayer = null;
float[] PlayerPosVec = new float[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

static Socket sock;

void Start()
{
    anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    IPEndPoint IPaddress = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("130.229.156.6"), 13000);

    try
    {
        sock.Connect(IPaddress);
    }
    catch
    {
        Debug.Log("Unable to connect");
    }
    byte[] MSGFromServer = new byte[1024];
    int size = sock.Receive(MSGFromServer);

    string inPut = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(MSGFromServer, 0, size);
    Debug.Log("Jag ar player " + inPut);
    ImPlayer = inPut;
    InvokeRepeating("Send", 1.0f, 0.125f);
}
    // weapon variables
    public float bulletSpeed = 10.0f;
    public float bulletDestroyTime = 5.0f; // after 5-sec dissapear (bullet)
    public GameObject bulletObject;
    public Transform bulletSpawnPoint;

    void Start()
    {

    }
    void Update()
    {
        Shoot(); 
    }
    void Shoot()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0))
        {
           var bullet = (GameObject)Instantiate(
           bulletObject,
           bulletSpawnPoint.position,
           bulletSpawnPoint.rotation);

           bullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = bullet.transform.forward * bulletSpeed;

           Destroy(bullet, bulletDestroyTime);
        }

    }
```

Comment: I'm not seeing any networking code in there at all, how do you suppose the server is supposed to know what you're doing?

Comment: Typically networking APIs like uNET or Photon that Unity uses have RPC calls that make things like these easy. You mention you "created your own server" so i think your would have to implement something similar yourself.

Comment: Might want to start with Network.Instantiate(bulletObject, tbulletSpawnPoint.position, bulletSpawnPoint.rotation)

Comment: @oxrock I  did not added it to the code I thought u don t need that part but there u go..

Comment: Do not use Socket. You can't use socket without using or knowing anything about Threads. Use Unity UNet which simply everything. [Here](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/s/multiplayer-networking) is a tutorial. Follow and complete it and you'll be able to make a network game.